# Formato de salida en excel desde python

Tags: python, excel

¿Cómo podría cambiar el formato de salida de un dataframe en formato excel para que se vea el fondo en rojo y las letras en blanco de el nombre de las columnas (header) de mi dataframe?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Usando pandas?

Comment: Sí, usando pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comencemos por crear un pequeño dataframe de muestra:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Ejemplo1":  [5, 8, 2, 9], "Ejemplo2": [8,4,3,5]})
print(df)
```

El resultado es:

```
   Ejemplo1  Ejemplo2
0         5         8
1         8         4
2         2         3
3         9         5
```

### Conversión a Excel con formato en las cabeceras

Las cabeceras de la tabla son algo que requiere hacer ciertas "trampas". Estilos en las celdas podrían crearse usando los estilos de pandas (a través de `df.style`) y esos estilos se mantienen al exportar a excel si se usa el *backend* `openpyxl`. Pero las cabeceras van aparte y nunca se mantiene el formato.

El truco es por tanto el siguiente:

1. Usar `xlsxwriter` (necesitas tenerlo instalado, con `pip`)
2. Usarlo para exportar el dataframe pandas, pero quitando las cabeceras (dejando no obstante la primera fila libre para meter las cabeceras a posteriori)
3. Usarlo de nuevo para acceder al formato excel exportado y añadir directamente sobre el excel las cabeceras que no habíamos volcado, usando las capacidades de esta librería para añadir el formato que se desee a cada celda.
4. Guardar la hoja así modificada

Estos pasos se traducen en el siguiente código:

```py
# 1. Preparar xlsxwriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("ejemplo.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# 2. Usarlo para volcar el dataframe, pero sin las cabeceras
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Hoja1', startrow=1, header=False)

# 3. Usarlo de nuevo para modificar la excel
workbook  = writer.book                 
worksheet = writer.sheets['Hoja1']  # Acceder a la hoja en cuestión

header_format = workbook.add_format({  # crear el formato deseado
    'bold': True,
    'font_color': '#FFFFFF',
    'bg_color': '#C00000',
    })

# Iterar por todos los nombres de columna y crear cada una de ellas
# directamente en la fila 0 de la excel, con el formato deseado
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)

# 4. Guardar resultado
writer.save()
```

He aqui una captura de pantalla de Excel tras abrir nuestro fichero.

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Ha quedado perfecto! Muy bien explicado y ocurrente.